# Buy subscription with paypal through IPN, paypal response slower than buy item with no subscription

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm having a problem with IPN paypal response. I'm using cmd = '_xclick-subscriptions';

And code to post back paypal is:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

But after done payment, I must wait sometime to 2 or 3 mins to paypal response to update my database.

I can't understand about this problem. Any ideas to help me, please.

P/s: my domain is: http://ecomdev.sitelantern.com

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that has meaning. The fact your question is about PayPal IPN is clear from the tags you used, and removing that from the title leaves *Post again about*, which has zero meaning. Your title should clearly describe the question you're asking or problem you're having in a way that will have meaning to future readers who see it in a search result. Being clear in the title also helps get the attention of users who might be able to help, getting you an answer faster.

Comment: Hi Ken, I changed my question title. Could you help me to check, plz